An 18-Letter Challenge-A: three 6-letter words, with limitations
Use the following 22 letters to make three 6-letter words (it's the alphabet w/o H, M, Q, and S):

ABCDEFGIJKLNOPRTUVWXYZ

Here are the limitations:

Use YAWL for wordlist: https://github.com/elasticdog/yawl/archive/master.zip
Each letter can be used only once.
Maximum of 5 vowels between the three words, including Y. (Feel free to sequentially use the 21-letter alphabets below, each of which omits one vowel.)
C and V must be used.
These words are invalid, do not use them: KRANTZ, PLONGD, PRANCK.

Per my attempts, BLINTZ appears to be the only 1-vowel word that can be built from this letter pool, which results in completed wordlists like F*CKED/VAPORY (which uses all 5 other vowels) or UPWARD/JOCKEY & GAWKED/CROUPY (each of which both exhausts all 5 vowels and doesn't use V). This makes BLINTZ feel like a dead end; I would love to be proven wrong. Happy hunting!
BCDFGJKLNPRTVWXZEIOUY / BCDFGJKLNPRTVWXZAIOUY / BCDFGJKLNPRTVWXZAEOUY
BCDFGJKLNPRTVWXZAEIUY / BCDFGJKLNPRTVWXZAEIOY / BCDFGJKLNPRTVWXZAEIOU
PS: Should this wind up impossible, try this alternate and equally impossible challenge:
An 18-Letter Challenge-B: three 6-letter words, with limitations

I will do that.

Via integer linear programming, the unique solution is

 {'BLINTZ','UPGROW','VACKED'}


YAWL will be the GD death of me. Vacked not accepted, but I don't have a better wordlist to link to than YAWL, so fantastic. Thanks for that, anyhow: you rock!
